# Trouble running a .pkg program as an admin

Tags: c#, uac

At my work's sites, we have update packages that need to be run locally and synched with a small printer. These updates are of a .pkg format and when double-clicked should open a sync tool. Our sites are blocked to run any executables like this so a UNC prompt comes up and we need to enter our passwords and I'm looking for another way so we don't have to intervene everytime.

I've started a program that will open this file and run it under a domain admin account but the method process.start gives me the error "the specified executable is not a valid application for this os platform". To get around that, I've seen that I need to change the UseShellExecute property to True but doing this doesn't allow me to run it as a user so I'm back to the original problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions or alternative methods to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you could do this, it would defeat the entire purpose of UAC. If you need to make an exception for this type of executable, then properly make an exception in your policy for this type of executable, instead of trying to hack around the issue. If you could just programmatically bypass the need to provide credentials for an admin when running as a non-admin, you might as well turn off UAC totally because it would be meaningless.

Comment: What executable uses the .pkg file, and why does it need to be run as an administrator (elevated)?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still relatively new to GP settings but where can I add an exception for this type of executable so UAC doesn't prompt for it? I have set the file type under the Inclusion list for low types but I still get prompted.

Comment: If a non-elevated user starts an executable that requires elevation, there is no way to bypass the elevation prompt if UAC is enabled. This is by design. I think you need to give more details about your goal rather than your attempted solution.